# yield is a reserved keyword error inside async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I need to use window.chrome.storage to get the user email from the chrome storage and check if that email matches with the user logged in email from the response.data.email. if it matches, then dispatch success function else error. However, I am getting an error of 'yield is a reserved keyword'. How do i then make it work?

here is what i have done

```
function* setSessionAndLogin(response, headers, successCB, failureCB) {
    if (response.data) {
        const sessionValue = Array.from(headers.entries()).reduce(
            (val, entry) => ({ ...val, [entry[0]]: entry[1] }),
            {}
        );

    // const results = yield call(() => {})
    window.chrome.storage.sync.get(['user_email'], result => {
      if (response.data.email === result.user_email) {
        yield put(successCB(response.data));
        window.chrome.storage.sync.set(
                { user_token: btoa(JSON.stringify(sessionValue)) },
                function() {}
            );
      } else {
            yield put(failureCB('Email does not match'));
        }
    });

    } else {
        yield put(failureCB(response.errors[0]));
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Solutions i tried

solution 1.

Here nothing happens. I don't get error but also console.log('result', result, result.user_email); does not prints anything in the console.

```
function* setSessionAndLogin(response, headers, successCB, failureCB) {
    if (response.data) {
        const sessionValue = Array.from(headers.entries()).reduce(
            (val, entry) => ({ ...val, [entry[0]]: entry[1] }),
            {}
        );
        window.chrome.storage.sync.get(['user_email'], function*(result) {
            console.log('result', result, result.user_email);
            if (result.user_email && response.data.email === result.user_email) {
                yield put(successCB(response.data));
                window.chrome.storage.sync.set(
                    { user_token: btoa(JSON.stringify(sessionValue)) },
                    function() {}
                );
            } else {
                yield put(failureCB('Email does not match'));
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('error');
        yield put(failureCB(response.errors[0]));
    }
}
```

solution 2

```
const results = yield call(fetchUserEmail)
async function fetchUserEmail() {
    let userEmail = [];
    const email = await window.chrome.storage.sync.get(['user_email'], result => {
        userEmail.push(result.user_email);
        console.log('userEmail', userEmail);
    });

    return userEmail;
}
```

here i get empty array.

Comment: Your  `yield put(successCB(response.data))` and `yield put(failureCB('Email does not match')` seems to be part of a callback, and not of the generator function instead

Comment: Are you sure you meant `async` function as I don't really see the keyword here, but I do see the generator function (*) here. Also how will you use this function, are you sure a generator function is the correct approach here?

Comment: @Icepickle I have udpated my question with solutions i tried

Comment: You should really take a step back. At the moment it seems you are just trying out as many things as possible, but you make some interesting mistakes. In Solution 1, you yield to your callback, not inside the main generator function, so there your yield is well, completely unnecessary. Solution 2 uses a callback to update a block scoped variable, and you seem to await it, but that would mean that get would return you a promise (which seems unlikely as you provide a callback function as well). So step back, and analyse the problems (I do like solution 2 better, it looks simpler)

Comment: ... so check the documentation, see what are the possibilities, and then think how you can make it work, from what I see you seems to understand the language pretty well, so it seems like an information problem rather than a technical one ;)

Comment: thanks a lot and I appreciate you for such kind suggestion. The truth is I feel difficult to understand english language :). I cannot grasp from the documentation clearly.

Comment: It is good you found an answer, but either delete the question, or self answer your question. Having it as part of the question makes the distinction between question and answer a bit hard ;) Good that you took a step back, it looks lots more readable than your first attempt ;)

Comment: thanks answered it so it will help others either.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this using promise. If async operation has to be carried inside generator, one option you can do is the following way.

call the function using `yield call(fetchUserEmail)`. This is a bit readable and organized way to do in some extent. I do not know about async/await so the answer in async/await is highly appreciated. Solution in different ways gives different idea to solve the problem and thus increases the knowledge on various domain.

```
function fetchUserEmail() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let userEmail = [];
        window.chrome.storage.sync.get(['user_email'], result => {
            userEmail.push(result.user_email);
            resolve(userEmail);
        });
    });
}
```